# Dynamically calling an object's private functions

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to dynamically call the private method `add` from a public function. It seems that `this` only accesses the public scope which is why I'm not able to call `add`. Is there a way to do this?

```
function test()
{
    var actionCollection = [];

    function add( int1, int2 )
    {
        return int1 + int2;
    }

    this.callFunc = function( testMethodFunction, methodArguments )
    {
        this[testMethodFunction].apply(null, methodArguments);//Method 'add' not found.
    }
}

var t = new test();

alert( t.callFunc( 'add', [1,2] ) );
```

Plus I'm not exactly sure what `null` is supposed to do considering you can also use `this` in the `apply` argument. Could I also have some clarification on what the first argument of `apply` is supposed to do? Since this is also related to my original question. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: @Andreas I already read that, I'm still not clear on the purpose of the first argument however.

Comment: The first argument specifies the value which is accessible via `this` in the function. `function foo() { console.log("this.bar = " + this.bar); } foo.apply({ bar: 5 }, null);` will log `this.bar = 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add` is not a part of `this`. Therefore you cannot use `this[testMethodFunction]`. If you want to keep privacy, then you can use something like this:

```
function test() {
    var actionCollection = [];

    var private_methods = {
        add: function( int1, int2 ) {
            return int1 + int2;
        }
    }

    this.callFunc = function( testMethodFunction, methodArguments )
    {
        // note the change here!
        return private_methods[testMethodFunction].apply(null, methodArguments);
    }
}

var t = new test();

alert( t.callFunc( 'add', [1,2] ) );
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Accepted since it was the first correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because `add()` is not a property of `Test`, it is only a local variable in the `Test()` closure.

Here's a sample code:

```
function Test()
{
    var _priv = {
        add: function ( int1, int2 )
        {
            console.log(int1, int2);
            return int1 + int2;
        }
    };

    this.callFunc = function( testMethodFunction, methodArguments )
    {
        console.log(_priv);
        return _priv[testMethodFunction].apply(null, methodArguments);
    }
}

var t = new Test();

console.log(t);

console.log( t.callFunc( 'add', [1,2] ) );
```

Some tips for you:

- Do use upper case for Class-like constructs (`Test` instead of `test`)
- Use `log()` to your advantage to inspect objects